# Count field values with more than one occurence in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a collection like

```
_id: ObjectId("568f93b5e0ce9f35377c723e")
 rollNo: "123"

 _id: ObjectId("568f93b5e0ce9f35377c723g")
 rollNo: "111"

 _id: ObjectId("568f93b5e0ce9f35377c723g")
 rollNo: "123"
```

i want to query and get the count of distinct roll nos. For eg from my above collection i should get the count as 2. and i also i would like to print the roll nos whose occurrence is more than one for eg from my above collection roll no 123 should be printed.

I tried with

```
db.student.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$rollNo",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
],function(err,result) {

});
```

this will print every roll number followed by its count. My collection is very huge and hence its difficult to track . Is there any other simpler way i can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so; this is a disadvantage of MongoDB. You might be able to improve performance by indexing the field.

Comment: I never said its a disadvantage, my problem is i have 1 million documents and this keeps printing every document and the count of it, its difficult to track those. I need the count of only distinct roll nos.

Comment: Then your question is unclearly phrased; it was not clear that you were getting duplicates of particular roll numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get the count of distinct field you can take advantage of [distinct command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) which returns an array of distinct values for a field; you can check the length of the array for a count.

```
db.student.distinct("rollNo").length
```

In order to print the roll nos whose occurrence is more than one you can take advantage of [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator after grouping:

```
db.student.aggregate([     
    {"$group": {"_id": "$rollNo", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}}, 
    {"$match": {count: {"$gt": 1}}} 
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb allows us to get distinct values according to document's fields.

```
db.student.distinct("rollNo");
```

This command returns `[123,111]`

```
db.student.distinct("rollNo").length;
```

This shell command will return count of distinct rollNo field.

Also you might get count of specific key with reduce method. Here is the [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/single-purpose-aggregation/).

```
db.student.group({
   key: { rollNo: 1 },
   reduce: function(cur, result) { result.count += cur.count },
   initial: { count: 0 }
});
```

So you will get a resultset like this ;

```
[
  { rollNo: 123, count: 2 },
  { rollNo: 111, count: 1 }
]
```

I don't know which java library(or just mongodb driver) you use but you can adapt that mongo shell commands into your code.

Comment: Do we have any other solutions , for the 1st solution with distinct i am getting an error as : "errmsg" : "exception: distinct too big, 16mb cap",
and with reduce method i am getting error as "errmsg" : "errmsg: \"group() can't handle more than 20000 unique keys\"",. My collection has  4 million documents.

Comment: yes `.group` method restricted with 16mb doc size, the other solution is `aggregation` with same requirements like Volodymyr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may further extend your pipeline as below. This will not completely solve your problem. But the output of this contains much fewer records, which you can easily process in app.

```
pipeline = [
  { 
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$rollNo",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$count',
      rollNos: {$addToSet: '$_id'},
      rollCount: {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
];
```

The above gives distinct role numbers for each count. You can now iterate through results to find total rollCount. Filter the get rollNos that appeared more than once.